# IIS hosted WCF service executing Git commands hangs

Tags: git, wcf, iis

Ive written a WCF service which I host in IIS, so far so good.

The service runs under my own account during developement (app pool is my user).

The service executes a git clone command to start with like so:

```
        var process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory ?? _pathToRepository;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = _pathToGitExecutable;
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = command;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => Debug.WriteLine(args.Data);
        process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, args) => Debug.WriteLine(args.Data);

        process.Start();

        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();

        process.WaitForExit();
```

Argument is: clone https://github.com/XXXX/YYYY

Or: clone git@github.com:XXXX/YYYY

When calling the service I get to (debugview):

```
Cloning into 'YYYY'...
```

If I inspect the path I can see a new directory (YYYY) as expected and the .git folder, but then nothing more happens.

If I run the command by hand it works fine.

Its VERY possible that the command is hanging waiting for some input (user/pass/other) due to the IIS during impersonation in some other way then for ex. a windows service would, but I have no way of telling as I get no feedback on either StdErr/StdOut.

Can anyone think of a way I can move forward and identify the problem?

**UPDATE**

Ive tried with the HOME variable but no dice:

```
        process.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables.Remove("HOME");
        process.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables.Add("HOME", System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile));
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by doing a more "correct" and async implementation for the process wrapper like so:

public interface IProcessRunner
    {
        void Start(string WorkingDirectory, string FileName, string Arguments);
        bool CompletedWithSuccess();
        string GetStandardOutput();
        string GetStandardError();
    }

```
public class ProcessRunner : IProcessRunner
{
    private readonly StringBuilder _standardOutput = new StringBuilder();
    private readonly StringBuilder _standardError = new StringBuilder();
    private readonly AutoResetEvent _standardOutputWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private readonly AutoResetEvent _standardErrorWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private int _processExitCode = -1;

    public void Start(string WorkingDirectory, string FileName, string Arguments)
    {
        var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                WorkingDirectory = WorkingDirectory,
                FileName = FileName,
                Arguments = Arguments,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            },
        };

        process.OutputDataReceived += process_OutputDataReceived;
        process.ErrorDataReceived += process_ErrorDataReceived;
        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();

        process.WaitForExit();
        _standardErrorWaitHandle.WaitOne(1000);
        _standardOutputWaitHandle.WaitOne(1000);

        _processExitCode = process.ExitCode;
    }

    private void process_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data == null)
        {
            _standardErrorWaitHandle.Set();
        }
        else
        {
            _standardError.AppendLine(e.Data);
        }
    }

    private void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data == null)
        {
            _standardOutputWaitHandle.Set();
        }
        else
        {
            _standardOutput.AppendLine(e.Data);
        }
    }

    public bool CompletedWithSuccess()
    {
        return _processExitCode == 0;
    }

    public string GetStandardOutput()
    {
        return _standardOutput.ToString();
    }

    public string GetStandardError()
    {
        return _standardError.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: To be honest I actually ended up abandoning this solution alltogether and found a much cleaner way of solving my problem which did NOT include Git commands :). But I have posted the runner as a help for others.